# Xcode - Swift Compiler Error For Bridging header

Tags: swift, xcode, bridging-header

I'm attempting to use a Bridging header but when I try to run my application I get a swift compiler error, when I remove the bridging header and the header file the app runs.

This is the error message I get:

```
<unknown>:0: error: generate-pch command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

My app has spaces in it's name and I'm denoting that by adding hyphens instead of spaces. I attempted to remove the space by using a backslash and a space like "${SRCROOT}/Project\ Name/headerFile.h" but I got this error message:

```
<unknown>:0: error: error opening input file '/Users/apple/Documents/Folder/Project Name/Project\ Name/HeaderFile.h' (No such file or directory)
```

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this by using just spaces instead of hyphens or backslash and spaces. Simple enough.